# Apexcharts hide a series on load

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

How to hide the first series on inital load using apexcharts react?
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-jones-49zq5r?file=/src/chart/BaseOption.js:2420-2433
My goal is to make so the first series is disabled on initial load. But not quite sure how to do this?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts";
import BaseOptionChart from "./BaseOption";
const Demo = () => {
  const xaxis = {
    ...BaseOptionChart().xaxis,
    categories: [
      "2018-09-19T00:00:00.000Z",
      "2018-09-19T01:30:00.000Z",
      "2018-09-19T02:30:00.000Z",
      "2018-09-19T03:30:00.000Z",
      "2018-09-19T04:30:00.000Z",
      "2018-09-19T05:30:00.000Z",
      "2018-09-19T06:30:00.000Z"
    ]
  };
  const series = [
    {
      name: "series1",
      data: [31, 40, 28, 51, 42, 109, 100]
    },
    {
      name: "series2",
      data: [11, 32, 45, 32, 34, 52, 41]
    }
  ];
  const legend = {};
  const values = {
    ...BaseOptionChart(),
    xaxis
  };
  console.log(values);
  return <ReactApexChart type="area" options={values} series={series} />;
};
export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

check this apex chart method in react to access the documentation methods you must create an instance as follows:

import below packages:

```
    import Chart from 'react-apexcharts'
    import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'

//options relevants for chart:

const options = {
chart: {
    id: 'chartBarSeries',-> give a id
    type: 'bar',
...etc,
// in render method

            <Chart
                options={varOptions}
                series={varSeries}
                type="line"
                height={'auto'}
            />
// in a effect or button function

 

                const chart = ApexCharts.getChartByID('chartBarSeries')
                chart.hideSeries('your series name')-> or another method
```